# Insert a thymeleaf fragment into a thymeleaf layout

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Im using Sping boot(1.5.3.RELEASE), thymeleaf and thymeleaf layout dialect. I have a fragment called breadcrumb.html(/templates/fragments):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<ul th:fragment="breadcrumb" th:each="link : ${session.currentBreadCrumb}">
 <li th:text="${link.label}"></li>
</ul>
</html>
```

And I have layout layout.html(/templates/layouts)

```html
  

  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/web/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
<title>Layout page</title>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <h1>My website</h1>
 </header>
 <div layout:include="../fragments/breadcrumb :: breadcrumb"></div>
 
 <section layout:fragment="content">
  <p>Page content goes here</p>
 </section>
 <footer>
  <p>My footer</p>
  <p layout:fragment="custom-footer">Custom footer here</p>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a home.html(/templates)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/web/thymeleaf/layout" layout:decorator="layouts/layout">
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Is what I'm trying to do achievable? Am i missing something silly?

Kind regards,
Dave

Comment: You haven't defined layout:fragment="content" in home.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is to do with the version of thymeleaf. It seems that spring boot(1.5.3) doesn't play nice with this version of thymeleaf.

Check this post out: [Spring Boot Thymeleaf Layout Dialect Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42029024/spring-boot-thymeleaf-layout-dialect-not-working?rq=1)